# How to force usage of specific codec with ffmpeg?

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to read a certain video file using ffmpeg, and have run into a bit of trouble.

This is the code that starts to read it:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Filename is needed as an argument\n" );  
        return 1;  
    }
    /* register all formats and codecs */
    av_register_all();
    AVFormatContext* fmt_ctx = NULL;
    /* open input file, and allocate format context */
    const char *src_filename = argv[1];
    if (avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx, src_filename, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open source file %s\n", src_filename);
        abort();
    }
    /* retrieve stream information */
    AVDictionary *      options;
    int res = avformat_find_stream_info(fmt_ctx, &options);
    if (res < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find stream information\n");
        abort();
    }
    ...
}
```

I am consistently getting the following message:

> [avi @ 005f2fe0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video:
>   none (GREY  / 0x59455247), 1280x1024): unknown codec
>
> Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options

I get the same message when i run ffmpeg tool on the same file.

However, i know what is in the video stream - raw video data with YUV8 format. In fact, when i pass that to ffmpeg via `-c:v rawvideo` option, there is no problem. Recoding, transforming etc - ffmpeg does it like the magic tool it is.

Now, the question is: when using ffmpeg api, what is the equivalent of that option? I desperately need access to the frames of file.

Comment: you can try passing second param in avformat_find_stream_info as NULL.

Comment: i did before, it didn't work as well

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing second param in avformat_find_stream_info as NULL. As stream info read few packets to get some information about the streams present in the file. Also this message will not hamper your decoding. If you are planning to decode packets later this should be fine.
For decoding you will need to call avcodec_find_decoder and avcodec_open2().